# How to turn off scheduled tasks which I can't locate?

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler

[image]

The task has a weird GUID name which I can't seem to find anywhere. It triggers a shutdown for my PC every hour or so. I'm pretty sure it is this task. How do I find this in task scheduler and disable it?

Comment: Find the command executed in Task Scheduler Management Console. Or you may search registry to find that GUID.

Comment: What do you mean find the command executed in task scheduler? How do i do that?

Answer (score 3):

#### How do I find this in task scheduler and disable it?

1. Open an administrator `cmd` shell.
2. Run the following command to list all of the scheduled tasks with GUID names:

   ```
   schtasks /query | findstr "{"
   ```

   Example output:

   ```
   > schtasks /query | findstr "{"
   User_Feed_Synchronization-{0CB0E1B4-5524 31/05/2017 11:25:51    Running
   User_Feed_Synchronization-{F2ABD734-5170 30/05/2017 19:50:03    Ready
   {3C42F888-EE53-4541-A59C-8198AA251687}   N/A                    Ready
   {4A4CA98E-7F38-4290-9DFD-AA3AE17481F5}   N/A                    Ready
   {AA3255CA-EDE4-4B11-855E-A4A9A6FDE89D}   N/A                    Ready
   {C56B633B-E9D2-4155-987A-7FE8A962906F}   N/A                    Ready
   COMODO Autostart {D5EFF3B3-E126-4AF6-BCE N/A                    Running
   COMODO CMC {06A09C0F-DD9C-4191-A670-7111 31/05/2017 0:00:00     Ready
   COMODO Signature Update {B9D5C6F9-17D2-4 Disabled
   COMODO Update {A6D52E4F-569B-4756-B3D8-D Disabled
   ```
3. Run the following command to delete the appropriate task:

   ```
   schtasks /delete /tn "{GUID}" /f
   ```

   Where:

   - `{GUID}` is the name of the task to delete.
   - `/f` - Force delete, ignore warnings even if the task is currently runnning.

   Example:

   ```
   schtasks /delete /tn "{3C42F888-EE53-4541-A59C-8198AA251687}" /f
   ```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files.
- [schtasks](http://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html) - Create / edit a Scheduled Job/Task. The job can be created on the local or a remote computer.

Comment: This doesn't display all tasks

Comment: @SKLAK It displays all tasks with GUID names. To display all tasks use just `schtasks /query`

Comment: No it does not display all tasks with GUID names. I see guid named tasks in task scheduler, while this command only displays one GUID task name.

Comment: @SKLAK Are you running as an Administrator?

Comment: Yes, running cmd as admin

Comment: @SKLAK I've no idea why it is not working for you. Working fine here. Can you provide some screenshots?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/1fpYLCm.png

Comment: @SKLAK Can you please try the following command? `schtasks /query /v /fo list | findstr "{"`

Comment: @DavidPostill Still an issue https://snipboard.io/kvaqQc.jpg